# QML BusyIndicator while loading a heavy qml file

Tags: qt, qml, loader, busyindicator

I've been trying to run a BusyIndicator (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-busyindicator.html) while I am loading a qml file (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html), but the BusyIndicator doesn't appear.

What I am trying to do is:
1- The user emits a "handlerLoader(name)", where "name" is the url of the next qml page.
2- In "onHandlerLoader" I run the busyIndicator.
3- Then, I change the Loader source.

The problem is that no matter the time I spent between steps 2 and 3, the BusyIndicator does not appear.

Moreover, when I comment step 3, the busyIndicator appears correctly.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

This is the code:

```
Rectangle {

    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
    signal handlerLoader (string name)
    Loader {
        id: pageLoader;
        source: "init.qml";
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        id: busyIndicator_inicio
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        running: false
    }

    Connections {
        target: pageLoader.item
        onHandlerLoader: {
             busyIndicator_inicio.running = true
             pageLoader.source = name;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason is, that your heavy-loading `Loader` is blocking the thread.
Set it to asynchronous mode, to allow the rest of the program to run.
Further, I'd recommend to prefer declarative bindings to imperative assignments in handlers. See my example:

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

Window {
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: 'load'
        onClicked: {
            loader.source = "TestObj.qml"
        }
    }

    Loader {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id: loader
        active: true
        asynchronous: true
        visible: status == Loader.Ready
    }

    BusyIndicator {
        id: ind
        anchors.fill: parent
        running: loader.status == Loader.Loading
    }
}
```

TestObj.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Grid {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: width
        rows: height
        Repeater {
            model: 100
            Rectangle {
                width: { for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) console.log(i); return 1 }
                height: 1
                color: 'green'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the asynchronous `Loader` might display incomplete files for some time, I set it to be visible only when its `status` changes to `ready`.